# How to get subdomain fu working in development on my local machine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain-fu

I cloned a github repo using subdomain fu but I can't seem to get the site to load properly. I always get the same error:

I tried signin.localhost.local:3000, which seems to be working to get the signin/signup pages working. However, when I go to login (from signin.localhost.local:3000) it keeps "signin" at the front like so:

```
sub1.signin.localhost.local:3000
```

in prod it works perfectly but for some reason it keeps signin here when it is not suppose to. Also, if I try just removing "signin" and going to sub1.localhost.local:3000, it tells me again "can't find account with subdomain = ". very frustrating.

Here is my hosts file right now:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost signin.localhost.local sub1.localhost.local signup.localhost.local
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with subdomains in development mode can be really tricky. If you're on a Mac and the project is using a reasonably recent version of Rails, I'd recommend using [Pow](http://pow.cx) which will let you use subdomains without any fancy trickery.

Once you've installed it, you can add a symlink to a project to your `~/.pow` directory and then access the app at `app_name.dev` and use subdomains, such as `signin.app_name.dev` as well.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion...but this is a cloned repo with subdomain fu already being used. I don't think I can change it now.

Comment: You don't need to change anything in the app to use Pow. It's a rack app server that you run locally -- it's basically a substitute for running `script/rails` or `rails server` in a terminal.

Comment: Tried that...but when I try to open the app it just lags out...i'd like to get this method working first before trying pow again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to confirm, you are restarting apache?

Comment: No, I haven't needed to do that thus far to get the little fixes I've got working. Didn't know I had to do that. I'm running this on my local machine.